# Clicktracking tools

Tags: analytics

Does anybody have any recommendations for affordable clicktracking tools. An initial search brought me to crazyegg, but I am curious if there are tools out there, that dont cost me a lot of money, but let me better understand, how people surf my site, apart from google analytics and friends.

Comment: Crazyegg's basic subscription is $9/month and you can try it for free for 30 days. How is that expensive? (I never used it by the way, but I'm thinking of using clicktale for a future project)

Comment: I'm in love with google analytics. I know its not what you are looking for but they are able to do this through onclick event to register and EventTrack or you can even set up and collect your own custom variables.

Answer (score 2):

one I'm aware of is clickheat: http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html . It's fairly easy to setup and use, but doesn't give you a lot of insights.

The best part (IMO) is that you don't need to process the clicks on the server-side in realtime, but is able to parse logs. Hence you can setup an url that quickly returns a status 204 (no content) and records the clicks.

**Update**: I forgot to say it's GPL software, free as in speech and as in beer. And you're not giving your valuable data away to third parties.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Clicktale](http://www.clicktale.com/), which also records mouse movemnt of visitors, creates click/mouse move heatmaps, and even more. You can use it for usability testing as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is more useful information rather than a full answer I suspect, but too long for a comment.

I'm currently trialing [ClickDensity](http://www.clickdensity.com/) where there's a 30 day trial period so you can see if it does what you want - then it's only $5/month for unlimited pages on 1 site. You add a bit of javascript to your top level home page. If you use wordpress like I do then you can just add it to a footer section.

I can see that while the hovermap info is ok, the clickmap and the heatmap do not merge information well from users who each had their browser set at different widths - thus for rows of buttons - it's not easy to tell which button was really clicked.

However - you can fix this partially by getting it to 'follow targets' when showing reports, but this then seems to lose information not associated with certain types of clickable targets - so for example clicks on my carousel are lost, but button clicks *are* shown correctly positioned.

Similar issues occur when users have a different text size to the browser you view the results on - but I guess that's...more challenging.

It's worth looking at because of the free (no credit card) trial and low monthly cost option, but I'm definitely going to be looking at other options - including *labsmedia Clickheat* [mentioned above or below](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/17408/6046) - although I can see that this too also does not merge information 100% correctly for differently sized user screens and text sizes.